# Xamarin maps don't show map in simulation

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maps

I am following a book and my app does navigate to the maps page I created and it shows location as expected per book but it doesn't show the map in background. The +/- zomm buttons on map doens't do anything as result as well.

My XAML

```
   <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <maps:Map x:Name="map" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
            <BoxView Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="White"
                Opacity=".8" />
            <StackLayout Padding="10" Grid.Row="1">
                <Label x:Name="title"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                <Label x:Name="date"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                <Label x:Name="rating"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                <Label x:Name="notes"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Any my AndroidMenifest.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.triplog2">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
    <application android:label="TripLog2.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
      android:value="YOUR-MAPS-API-KEY-HERE" />
  </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

And here is how my map screen looks like:

[image]

I don't know what the results would be for actual device (I haven't deployed it yet) but I would like to it work in simulation.

Comment: did you read the docs and perform the necessary config steps?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had done initialization of google maps etc (part of maps configurations as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/setup)) but the key part was this:

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
  android:value="YOUR-MAPS-API-KEY-HERE" />
```

I needed to generate my own value for YOUR-MAPS-API-KEY-HERE.

This is covered [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key?tabs=windows) but the article is dated 06/25/2018 (and its 11/06/2020 now) so a few screenshots are not exactly the same but you will figure it out.

However if you just want to see google maps in action quickly and not worry about too much security (for learning purposes), you can skip the `keytool` part and jump to `Creating an API Project`.

Essentially go to [Google Developers Console API & Services Dashboard](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard/) and follow the screenshots.

When you create the API Key credentials, essentially you get the key that you need to past in place for YOUR-MAPS-API-KEY-HERE. The rest of the steps is restrict its security.

[image]

The final screenshot of settings that will work is here.

[image: Final Image]

For full details, see the article, this is the bare minimum to get going and doesn't have all details.

*** **Update** ***

If you do need to use the `keytool` to generate the SHA1 key, it's pretty simple too.

Launch command line and it will start in default location c:\windows\system32).

Type `keytool` and enter and it should be a recognized command (you will get its help).

Next run the actual command:

`keytool.exe -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\[YOUR_LOGIN]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

Replace the `[YOUR_LOGIN]` above with your actual username in windows. It will generate all the info that you can feed for full security/permissions (mainly you just need the SHA1 key)